# Relation between Dynamic Allocation and Executor.instances

Tags: apache-spark

As per [Can num-executors override dynamic allocation in spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352830/can-num-executors-override-dynamic-allocation-in-spark-submit), spark will take the

```
max(
  spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,   
  spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,
  spark.executor.instances
)
```

to calculate the initial number of executors to start with.

Does this mean, if we have below config, spark will always use 5 executors and does not start with 1 executor & scales up till 5 as needed?

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
spark.executor.instances = 5
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really be sure of this, we can have a look at the source code. I'm using Spark version 3.5.0 (the newest verison as the time of this post) source code for this answer.

We can see where the initial number of executors gets calculated in the [`getDynamicAllocationInitialExecutors`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L2590-L2615) method:

```scala
  /**
   * Return the initial number of executors for dynamic allocation.
   */
  def getDynamicAllocationInitialExecutors(conf: SparkConf): Int = {
    if (conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_INITIAL_EXECUTORS) < conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS)) {
      logWarning(s"${DYN_ALLOCATION_INITIAL_EXECUTORS.key} less than " +
        s"${DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS.key} is invalid, ignoring its setting, " +
          "please update your configs.")
    }

    if (conf.get(EXECUTOR_INSTANCES).getOrElse(0) < conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS)) {
      logWarning(s"${EXECUTOR_INSTANCES.key} less than " +
        s"${DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS.key} is invalid, ignoring its setting, " +
          "please update your configs.")
    }

    val initialExecutors = Seq(
      conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS),
      conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_INITIAL_EXECUTORS),
      conf.get(EXECUTOR_INSTANCES).getOrElse(0)).max

    logInfo(s"Using initial executors = $initialExecutors, max of " +
      s"${DYN_ALLOCATION_INITIAL_EXECUTORS.key}, ${DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS.key} and " +
        s"${EXECUTOR_INSTANCES.key}")
    initialExecutors
  }
```

So we see indeed that `initialExecutors` is the max value out of 3 values. Let's try to fill them in.

These values are given by you:

```scala
conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS) = 1
conf.get(EXECUTOR_INSTANCES).getOrElse(0) = 5
```

This value is not supplied by you but [it defaults](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/package.scala#L616-L619) to the value of `DYN_ALLOCATION_MIN_EXECUTORS`, so:

```scala
conf.get(DYN_ALLOCATION_INITIAL_EXECUTORS) = 1
```

If we now make this calculation, we get:

```scala
Seq(1, 1, 5).max = 5
```

So indeed, the initial number of executors will be 5 to start with!

Comment: thanks. Finally, in addition to above configs, if we had also set executorAllocationRatio = 0.5, does this mean spark will use 5 exe/2  = ~3 executors?

Comment: This will only happen if the executors are idling, so that means in practice this will only happen once the stage runs out of tasks to distribute to each executor.

Comment: is not that the default behaviour of Dynamic allocation even without executorAllocationRatio? ie. to give back executors to spark if application does not need.

Comment: Hmm this is diverging a little bit from the original question. I propose you make a new question about this topic? You can send me the link once you made it :)

Comment: new post for the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203397/dynamic-executor-allocation