# Dynamic Executor Allocation

Tags: apache-spark

As per [Can num-executors override dynamic allocation in spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352830/can-num-executors-override-dynamic-allocation-in-spark-submit), spark will take below, to calculate the initial number of executors to start with.

```
max(
  spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,   
  spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,
  spark.executor.instances
)
```

So in the below case spark will start with 10 executors  ie. max(1,10)=10, cannot scale up or down based on the load,  maxExecutors also set to 10.

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
spark.executor.instances = 10
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10
```

Question - what if had also set executorAllocationRatio=0.5, in that case does spark starts with 5 (ie. 10/2) executor and scales upto 10 executors as needed or Spark tries to manage complete workflow in only 5 executors ie. irrespective work load/tasks, spark always uses 5 executors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What will happen here is the following (for Spark version 3.5.0, the newest at the time of this post):

- Your cluster will start with 10 executors, following the rationale you gave.
- This number will stay at 10 until there are not enough running/pending tasks left. Once one or more of them are idle for a long enough time, they will start to get killed.

Now you may ask, what is the use of this `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio` then? Well, this is mostly relevant when your cluster is growing: to make sure you don't create too many extra executors that would (possibly) be processing tiny tasks.

We can see this in the source code in `ExecutorAllocationManager.scala`:

- [`maxNumExecutorsNeededPerResourceProfile`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala#L288-L321) calculates the maximum amount of executors needed to make the current calculation.
- The logic for making your cluster bigger/smaller is done in [`updateAndSyncNumExecutorsTarget`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala#L362-L389). It makes use of  that previous function:

```scala
  private def updateAndSyncNumExecutorsTarget(now: Long): Int = synchronized {
    if (initializing) {
      // Do not change our target while we are still initializing,
      // Otherwise the first job may have to ramp up unnecessarily
      0
    } else {
      val updatesNeeded = new mutable.HashMap[Int, ExecutorAllocationManager.TargetNumUpdates]

      // Update targets for all ResourceProfiles then do a single request to the cluster manager
      numExecutorsTargetPerResourceProfileId.foreach { case (rpId, targetExecs) =>
        val maxNeeded = maxNumExecutorsNeededPerResourceProfile(rpId)
        if (maxNeeded < targetExecs) {
          // The target number exceeds the number we actually need, so stop adding new
          // executors and inform the cluster manager to cancel the extra pending requests

          // We lower the target number of executors but don't actively kill any yet.  Killing is
          // controlled separately by an idle timeout.  It's still helpful to reduce
          // the target number in case an executor just happens to get lost (e.g., bad hardware,
          // or the cluster manager preempts it) -- in that case, there is no point in trying
          // to immediately  get a new executor, since we wouldn't even use it yet.
          decrementExecutorsFromTarget(maxNeeded, rpId, updatesNeeded)
        } else if (addTime != NOT_SET && now >= addTime) {
          addExecutorsToTarget(maxNeeded, rpId, updatesNeeded)
        }
      }
      doUpdateRequest(updatesNeeded.toMap, now)
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the comments of that code, your amount of executors will only decrease if one of them is idle for a sufficiently long time. So in your case, you will start with 10 executors. That will remain so until you run out of tasks to run, your executors start idling and then you start decreasing the number of executors.

For some more info on how this all works, I find the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala#L39-L99) at the top of that file is quite good!

Comment: thanks,I can completely understand all properties of dynamic allocation, went through many doc, only part I I'm unable to completely follow is executorAllocationRatio. Lets say we have set minExecutor=1,maxExecutor=10, ratio=0.5, In this case spark starts with 1 executor and scales based on load. Here when we mention ratio of 0.5, are we saying for the any application , spark can scale only uptill 5 executors (ie. 10/2)  and not more than 5? if so why dont we set maxExecutor as 5 instead of mentioning Ratio? OR this scales up only by 0.5% of target executor each time, can go upto 10 if needed?

Comment: No, Spark will still increase the number of executors until a maximum of 10 executors if the workload is high enough. The allocation ratio just determines how fast you will get there. The `maxNumExecutorsNeededPerResourceProfile` I linked in the above post will be influenced by the allocation ratio parameter. In the code I pasted, `if (maxNeeded > targetExecs` (notice the < changed w.r.t. the code) you will add executors to target. The way you add them is preset (exponential growth 2^x). If this is not entirely clear you can make another question post as this comment is becoming too large.